# Direct xp from kills instead of drops

Tags: minecraft-commands

I'm trying to build a direct xp for kill command chain using the scoreboard commands to test for a score count and exchange it for xp instead of dropping orbs
I'm using `/scoreboard players test @a Kills 1 [1]` and scoreboard players remove `@a Kills 1` commands in chain command blocks but its not outputting so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Test/check/match only commands are rarely needed, you can save those for better performance and less commands. Does it work with `/scoreboard players remove @a[kills=1..] kills 1`? Also, what did you intend to do with `[1]`? It isn't part of any command syntax.

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it does not specify which edition is being played.